# Slow insert performance google cloud SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, google-cloud-platform, pentaho

I have a simple pentaho transformation: One input from SQL Server, and two outputs, one to local MySQL and another to Google cloud MySQL. The total rows from input are 3000 with six columns

My problem is that in Google cloud MySQL ouput is too slow, the performance is 6 minutes in to insert 3000 rows!, howerever in local MySQL output the performance is 1 second.

is there any reason for this problema?, Can I fix it?.

[Pentaho Transformation image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwO6v.png)

Thanks!

EDIT:

BEFORE INSERT

[Screenshot before insert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIqtB.png)

AFTER INSERT

[Screenshot after insert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBms1.png)

Comment: Your question has no details that can help with a solution. The first thought that comes to mind is "connection management". Are you creating a new connection for each request? Are you using Cloud SQL Proxy? What does the INSERT request look like? What size instances? I use both Cloud SQL for MySQL and standalone MySQL on GCE. I do not have any issues with either. In the SQL world, 3000 rows is nothing. Unless you have huge rows with binary data, 3000 rows should fit into memory with very fast response times.

Comment: To extend on what John said, if you're running one server local to your client, and another server across a WAN with thousands of round trips (e.g. to reestablish a connection for every row, or even just to insert a row one a a time in serial), of course the second is going to be much slower.  Minutes vs seconds does sound a bit excessive though, unless the data is quite large or your WAN bandwidth is quite low.  More details are definitely needed.

Comment: What is the commit size and are you using batch updates?

Comment: Hello everyone, thank u for your time!. I dont use cloud SQL proxy and don't know if I create a new connection for each request, how can I know?, can you help me?. The commit Size is 1000 row and use batch updates

Comment: Post your INSERT query, please, model of your Google Cloud instance ( so we can lookup the specs).

Comment: On your Google Cloud MySQL, from login root, SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'connections'; will reveal number of connections since start of instance.  Check it before and after pushing your data and you will have a clue how many connections are being requested. Please post your counts before/after.

Comment: Wilson, thank you for you tip. I did it, I create a new instance and  I didn't any query. Strangely the connections are rising uncontrollably. The value is 1700 and going up!

Comment: The number of connections in GLOBAL STATUS refers to the total number of connections made to the instance since it was started, not the number of currently active connections. This is why Wilson asked to provide a read before and after the insert operation. Also, please provide the full INSERT statement details.

Comment: On your Google Cloud MySQL, from login root, SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'thread%'; will reveal number of threads RUNNING and CONNECTED when requested. Check counts before and after pushing your data and you will have a clue how many threads are being managed. Please post your counts before/after.

Comment: Wilson, look the edit post pls, thanks!

Comment: @CristóbalUribe Thanks for your threads before/after postings. When you want me to be aware of a new comment from you, please use leading atsign - thenWilsonHauck and I will be notified. Could you post same results of thread% and also B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'uptime%'; and C) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%connect%'; Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few things to verify in terms of Cloud SQL performance in this case:

1. Enable lock monitoring which can be used for performance tuning. [Here is how](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/diagnose-issues#lock)
2. If using a First Generation instance, using asynchronous mode might be much faster. [Here is how](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/diagnose-issues#tips)
3. Check the locations of the writer and database; sending data a long distance introduces latency.
4. Caching is extremely important for read performance, which may come into play depending on the query for the insert. The entire data set should fit in 70% of the instance’s RAM.
5. If the query is CPU intensive and constitutes the majority of the workload, the instance might be throttled; [increase the tier](https://cloud.google.com/sql/pricing#2nd-gen-pricing).
6. Since the connection to the database seems to be done from an external application, [here is how to set this up properly](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app). More information about the connection configuration and the insert statement is required to determine if indeed connections are established for each requests as suspected by others.
7. If using InnoDB ([mandatory for 2nd generation instances and recommended for 1st generation ones](https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq#innodb)), here are some [best practices](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-best-practices.html) to follow to optimize performance, from the official MySQL documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You should add this parameter to your connection parameter:
rewriteBatchedStatements=true

This will drastically improve the inserts speed.
Check this for more info: https://anonymousbi.wordpress.com/2014/02/11/increase-mysql-output-to-80k-rowssecond-in-pentaho-data-integration/